# How to downgrade Xcode without apple developer account?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

I've recently upgraded my Xcode to 6.3.

Now I'm experiencing a lot of errors in my project, which I'm not capable of debugging.

Is it possible to downgrade it to 6.2 version if I don't have Apple Developer account?

Comment: Get it from your Time Machine backup! – But seriously, you should be able to update your project to Swift 1.2. There are release notes, lots of SO questions with answers, and a "Convert to latest Swift syntax" option in Xcode.

Comment: Why don't you try asking questions about some of the errors to see if we can fix them?

Answer (score 6):

go into the applications folder (Click on Finder icon > On the Sidebar, you'll find "Applications", click on it ), delete the "Xcode" icon. That will remove Xcode from your system completely. Restart your mac.

Actually there is no need to "downgrade". Just download Xcode 6.2 from the Apple developer download pages, and install it. Give it a name different from Xcode 6.3's name (e.g. call it "Xcode 6.0.2") and they can happily live side by side.

link : https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode

Answer (score 0):

You can download XCode 6.2 from developer.apple.com and can install it along with 6.3. You don't even need to remove 6.2. While installing 6.2  it will ask to replace, stop or keep both, so click both and you will have both version of xcode installed. While opening your project right click on xcodeproj file and select the xcode 6.2 version.

I have 2-3 version of xcode installed on my machine like 5.0, 6.2 and 6.3. Though this will slow your machine so won't recommend that

Answer (score 0):

Enjoy version 6.2 [Click here to download](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_6.2/Xcode_6.2.dmg)

You can change the version now and can download any of them.